# Exploiting the voice chat feature in Game Centre to create a Skype-like voip app?

Tags: objective-c, ios, voip, game-center, gamekit

So one can use AVAudioSession and GKVoiceChatService classes to set up voice chat in ones application like [this](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/GameKit_Guide/AddingVoiceChat/AddingVoiceChat.html). Now, is it possible to extend the same feature to creating full featured voip apps the sole purpose if which is device-to-device voice chat.

Assuming this is possible, would Apple approve non-gaming apps that uses this feature?

Comment: Who knows for sure? You could be the first to find out.  :-)

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GameKit/Reference/GKVoiceChatService_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/GKVoiceChatService/isVoIPAllowed

Answer (score 0):

They do allow other game center features for use in non game center apps.  They allow the bluetooth/ad hoc networking.  Similar apps to bump use it, so why not?